# Problem creating unique values to create a relationship in Power BI

Tags: relationship, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to join two tables together through a relationship but am having trouble.

My data is of a Building (type text) , which has Floors and Rooms which can both be a mix of text and number names (type any).

[image]

In order to create a relationship based on the Room column, I attempted to create a unqiue values table by referencing the Room_Mapping table, removing all by columns apart from Room, and removing duplicates.

[image]

However, when I try to join the two tables together based on the Room column, I keep getting the following message.

[image]

I have a feeling that this error is coming because the data type is a mix of text and numbers that it is getting confused because when I go to look at the data in Data view, I can see that the data for Phase and Room fields have been converted to Text type.

[image]

Please can any one help?  I have attached a link to the workbook and data in the link below.

[Room_Mapping Data and PBI Workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EgA0qNKE_h3A0kJQHMt3t-qlMb2LSiV3)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Room1/ROOM1 Room2/ROOM2 are the cause of your problem. You can solve this by adding one extra step to your Query.

[image]

You do this by right-clicking the Room column and choose `Transform > Capitalize Each Word`.

Comment: Thank so much! This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have 4 very similar cells:

Room1
ROOM1
Room2
ROOM2

in original table and them are duplicated yet in the Room_UniqueValues Table.

Try to replace this values like this in the Room_UniqueValues Table:

[image]

And null by "null" in the original table, for example:

[image]

Tell me if this are ok please!

Comment: Thank so much! This really helped!